# Error installing sparklyr version 0.8.4

Tags: r, installation, sparklyr

I'm trying to install the latest version of sparklyr "0.8.4" from the following link https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/releases/tag/v0.8.4.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/sparklyr-0.8.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Then the following message comes out

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
* installing *source* package 'sparklyr' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (sparklyr)
In R CMD INSTALL

packageVersion("sparklyr")
[1] ‘0.8.4’
```

I get the following error

```
> library(sparklyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sparklyr’ in get(method, envir = home):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/sparklyr/R/sparklyr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

*Any idea how to solve this error.*

**Note:** My `R.version` is 3.4.4 and my [Spark 2.3.1](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) version.

Comment: Did you try to restart the R session? According to https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/592 that is the first thing one should try.

Comment: I restarted the rstudio session but decided to install version 0.8.0, which supports Spark 2.3.1 `install.packages ("https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/archive/v0.8.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`. Now sparklyr works Thanks Ralf Stubner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the old version of **sparklyr 0.7**, then restart Rstudio finally use the following code, which installs the latest version from the CRAN.

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sparklyr_0.8.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```